# beamerposter - merge two columns at the end of the poster

Tags: beamer, columns, beamerposter

I am using [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/11207551xngbjdcbzkhd#/42275719/) to create a poster with `beamerposter`. I am trying to create a two-column poster, with the references occupying both columns at the end.

Here's my try. Basically what I did was to create first a huge one-column-wide poster, split it up in two for a while, and then re-merge it again right in the end. However, I can't understand why it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[final, 20pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[size=a0, scale=1.5]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usepackage{array, multirow, hhline}

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10} % Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
% Many more colors are available for use in beamerthemeconfposter.sty

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g. (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{96in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.464\paperwidth}
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.952\paperwidth}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%----------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{xxx % Poster title

\author{xxx} % Author(s)

\institute{\itshape xxx} % Institution(s)

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{.1\linewidth}

   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{.75\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{.1\linewidth}

   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of one big column - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=\twocolwid]

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{alertblock}{In a nutshell}

xxx

\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THEORETICAL BACKGROUND
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{xxx}

xxx

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MMNs
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{xxx}


    xxx

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ISSUES IN UH
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{xxx}

xxx

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATERIALS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{xxx}

xxxx

\end{block}

\end{column}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   METHODS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

%\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The second column

\begin{block}{Methods}

    xxx

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{xxx}

xxx

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{xxx}

xxx

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=red,bg=white} % Change the block title color

\begin{block}{xxx}

xxx

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=black,bg=norange} % Change the alert block title colors
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Change the alert block body colors

\begin{alertblock}{xxx}

xxx

\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the third column

\end{columns} % End of the column splitting

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{column}{\twocolwid}

\begin{block}{References}

%\nocite{*}
%\small{\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliography{SNLbiblio}}

\end{block}

\end{column}

%\end{column} 

\end{columns}

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

Any idea as to why the section `References` doesn't show up at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to compile the non-minimal example from your question (error `File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.`) and being so far from a minimal I did not want to debug, but basically you can just close the `columns` environment and continue after wards with normal text.

```
\documentclass[final, 20pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[size=a0, scale=1.5]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
\setlength{\parskip}{3em}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\lipsum[2]

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. I was thinking of it as much more complicated! Thanks!